# Category URL rewrite generating with categoryname (hypen + increment) for n store views

Tags: magento-1.8, category, url-rewrite, store-view

My website has 10+ store views, I observed that while creating new categories the default URL rewrite functionality of Magento is adding hyphen + increment id based on the store views count.

like example below

```
domain.com/us/abc-1.html for USA store view - Default store view
domain.com/uk/abc-2.html for UK store view
..
..
domain.com/fr/abc-10.html for France store view
```

Before adding the store views, we haven't faced issues like this. Can anybody help me on this to understand the logic and remove the (hyphen + increment id) from the URLs while generating itself?

Note: For the earlier generated category URLs before adding the store views, we have not faced the same issue. There it is working fine. Like below.

```
domain.com/us/xyz.html for USA store view - Default store view
domain.com/uk/xyz.html for UK store view
..
..
domain.com/fr/xyz.html for France store view
```